# How to call void function in other class?

Tags: iphone

I want to call one void function into many view controllers so how can i do it? please suggest me some idea.

Comment: Suggest us all some idea what you're talking about.

Comment: can't understand the question. do you just want to do something like `[viewController myMethod];`

Comment: @hardik: please clarify your question and add minimal code to illustrate what you're asking about. In particular, calling "into" view controllers doesn't make sense. Did you mean calling a function *from* a controller method? Do you want to call a function, a method or either? Also, what do you mean by "view controller"? Under the MVC architecture, views don't usually have separate controllers; instead, controllers send information to views for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you talking about static function.you have to declare and define that function as static , then you can use that void function without initializing the class in any view contorller. And also declare that static function as public.

static function declaration is this
+(void)functionName:(parametertype)parameter;

Comment: That's a "class method". C++ happens to use `static` to denote class fields and methods, but they're not the same thing. A "static function" would be a function declared with the "static" modifier, giving it internal linkage, which means it's only visible from within the same object file.